# The test of metal hydroxides and metal oxides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, metal

Is testing metal oxide different from testing metal hydroxide using a litmus paper?

Answer (score 1):

Litmus paper does not test for either metal oxides or metal hydroxides; indeed, it will not change color at all. Try it: put **dry** $\ce{CaO}$ on **dry** litmus paper. Litmus *does* change color with pH+, the negative log<sub>10</sub> ratio of $\ce{H+}$ ions to $\ce{OH-}$ ions (the ions may actually be more complex, such as $\ce{H3O+}$, but the idea is the same). This means the substance is in aqueous solution, i.e. in water.

Litmus also changes color with non-metals in solution, such as $\ce{NH3}$, which forms $\ce{NH4OH}$ in water, or with acetic acid, having an excess of $\ce{H+}$ ions.